# How to rotate emulator screen (not device orientation)?

Tags: android-emulator

Some apps run in landscape orientation, but sometimes allow you to see some picture in higher resolution by displaying it as portrait-oriented full screen image. Those are mostly games that allow you to tap character's portrait in profile to see it - Soccer Spirits, Chain Chronicle and and pretty much any other game that features character art as one of its draws.

IRL you supposed to turn your device to look at image, but how can I do that on Genymotion or any other emulator? It does have button to change device's orientation - i.e. internal state on what device thinks about it and will automatically turn screen accordingly, but it obviously doesn't help with apps that have fixed orientation.

Is there any way to just rotate emulator window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nox version 5.0.0.0 added this feature. Quote from changelog:

> 4. Added Rotate button to change Nox screen display from vertical to horizontal or back with just one click.